# rails: specify the HTTP verb in a redirect_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here's a basic overview of my domain:

- a user has a list of courses
- the user can "select" a course. The corresponding action is invoked with
  the PUT verb, stores the course_id in
  a session variable and redirects to
  the "show" action of the selected
  course.
- when the user has only 1 course available, I want to redirect him
  directly to the only course available (and
  invoke the "select" method before, of
  course).

From there, i see 2 options:

1. Keep the "select" action when the user clicks the link and add a new action for when the selection is automatic... but that doesn't look very DRY (even if I could refactor some code)
2. call the PUT action from the controller itself... but I haven't found how (is it even possible)?

Any alternative is welcome :)

Thanks for your help.

P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the courses controller:

```
def index
  @courses = Course.all
  if @courses.length == 1 #if only one course
    @course = @courses[0] #get that course
    session[:course_id] = @course.id #set the session
    redirect_to :action => "show", :param => "#{@course.id}" #redirect
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.xml  { render :xml => @line_items }
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I wanted to avoid duplicating the session[] part, but if there's no other choice, i think it will be a necessary evil.
I'll perhaps make it a standalone method.

Thanks!
P.

Comment: Pierre, try:

def show
  @course = Course.find(session[:course_id]

instead of

def show
  @course = Course.find(params[:id])

and you should be able to get rid of the param in the redirect_to line